# How to install Termux on old Android 5 devices ? (using the official archive)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, apk, termux, signature-error

**Context :**

Hello, I have a GPD XD console under Android 5 with a complex launcher. I would like to install the very good [Pegasus frontend](https://www.pegasus-installer.com/) (install and play, no tweaks), and for that they require to run a script through Termux (because it seems some commands like `/bin/bash` or `cURL` are included in Termux and are absent in other terminal apps).

For Android 5, there is an archive of the application available [here](https://archive.org/details/termux-repositories-legacy) (according to the official github).

**Problem:**

Unfortunately, I don't understand how to install these files on the console (there are too many of them). Indeed, I tried to install only the `termux-v0.79-offline-bootstraps.apk` file but I get an error message (maybe a `signature error` but I don't remember well).

**Question:**

Could you explain me step by step how to install these files please (and which ones to download) ? Thank you very much for your kind help!

Comment: Also be aware that **Pegasus** site states `If you already have termux make sure it is version 117. we've found issues on other versions.` and Termux version 117 requires Android 7.0 and up.

Comment: You should better search for a matching customROM for your device that bases on Android 7+.

Comment: Select any recent [build](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/actions/workflows/debug_build.yml). Download the APK suitable for your device (for example, https://github.com/termux/termux-app/suites/12269415843/artifacts/649696933). Install it.

Answer (score 2):

i have been using the old version ever since support for it was dropped. This is how i do it.
After installing **termux-v0.79-offline-bootstraps.apk** , you have to change the text in sources.list located `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/apt` (use `vi sources.list` ) to `deb https://packages.termux.dev/termux-main-21 stable main` . Use

```
apt remove science-repo
apt remove game-repo
```

Thats all, then to install packages just type;

`pkg install packageName`.
That's the easy way
**Manually**

You also have to install the dependecies manually from this same location

Visit

https://packages.termux.org/termux-main-21/dists/stable/main/binary-arm/
And just download the .deb file
Then navigate to your downloads folder and
type

```
dpkg -i package-name
```

Answer (score 1):

Support for Android 5 and 6 is back. See [the official page](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/wiki/Termux-on-android-5-or-6).

You can use [the archive link](https://archive.org/details/termux-repositories-legacy) to install any missing old packages. Press `show all`, then next to `termux-repositories-legacy-24.12.2019.tar`, press `(View Contents)`. Now you can find and download the packages you need without downloading the whole archive.